# ReferenceError: [BABEL] unknown: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.blacklist

Tags: gulp, babeljs, riot.js, babel-6

I'm getting this error while running my gulpfile. I'm assuming that there's something wrong with my Babel version.

[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
   "name": "riotjs-es6-structure",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "gulpfile.js",
   "dependencies": {},
   "devDependencies": {
       "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
       "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
       "babelify": "^7.3.0",
       "browserify": "^13.0.1",
       "graceful-fs": "^4.1.4",
       "gulp": "^3.9.1",
       "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
       "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
       "gulp-riot": "^0.5.1",
       "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
       "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
       "riot": "^2.4.1",
       "riotify": "^1.0.1",
       "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
       "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC"
   }
```

This is my .babelrc file

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

What did I miss? :(